How can i manage bitvector in C?
I have a generated program in c (it is used in cbmc) that contain that declarations:
unsigned __CPROVER_bitvector[1] __cs_active_thread[3] = {};
unsigned __CPROVER_bitvector[7] __cs_pc[3];
unsigned __CPROVER_bitvector[8] __cs_pc_cs[3];
unsigned __CPROVER_bitvector[2] __cs_last_thread;
unsigned __CPROVER_bitvector[7] __cs_thread_lines[3] = {66, 58, 108};

i have to make that program compilable by the GCC compiler, and i don't know how to do it.
I tried to find a library that manage the bitvector in c, but I didn't find anything.
How can i do?

Is the system that generates that code supposed to create actual C code? Otherwise it's not that hard to run the "code" though a filter to remove the __CPROVER_bitvector[.*] parts.

@Someprogrammerdude no it's not the system, the code is generated from a tool and i need that declarations, i can't remove them, so the idea is to find a library that manage bitvectors and map the type in the library with the type in my code

Then you need to give more information about the system you use. What is, for example, this "cbmc" you mention? While I doubt it's the "Christian Business Men's Connection", there are many other possibilities.

And please note that asking for library recommendations is not on topic here on SO.

CBMC is a tool for software security, you can find it here https://www.cprover.org/cbmc/
Sorry i didn't know that asking for library recommendations is not on topic here.
